# How Application.GetResourceStream Works?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I've embedded a Silverlight video file which is 15 MB in my silverlight assembly. I use `Application.GetResourceStream` to read the resource as an stream and then I pass the returned stream to the MediaElement control to start playing it.

**Question**: Does `Application.GetResourceStream` read the whole embedded file at once? If yes, Is there any solution to prevent this behaviour?

Note: I'm building an OOB silverlight application and it's going to be published using offline media(CD ROM), so don't worry about the enlarged xap file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the name Stream. That means it opens a file and reads from it sequentially (like a flowing stream).

Because of the nature of video players, which decompress streams on the fly, it will buffer a certain amount internally before playback starts. This allows the playback to stay ahead of the incoming data. For a locally stored file that will only be a small amount of data.

*Why were you concerned about it reading the whole file? Are you having performance problems or long delays?*

Comment: Thanks. I'm concerned about both of them, Because I have to embed large video files into my silverlight assembly, So I want the video to be played with the minimum delay, and I don't want the whole video to be read at once for memory issues.